# Como restar valores almacenados en una sola variable que son ingresados en un ciclo for en C#?

Tags: c#, bucle-for

Este es el código que tengo. Espero una respuesta.

```
Console.WriteLine("Cuántos números quiere restar?");
cantidad = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

for(int i = 0; i < cantidad;i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Digite un número");
    numero = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    resta = //Acá no sé que operación debo poner para que se resten
}

Console.WriteLine("La resta de los números es: " + resta);
```

Comment: Bienvenida, tienes algún ejemplo de la entrada y el resultado esperado?

Comment: Por ejemplo, el usuario quiere ingresar 5 numeros, pues 5 veces va a pedir un numero, y esos 5 numeros se van a restar.
Ingreso los numeros 10, 3, 2, 1, 1; la resta debería ser 3

Comment: Hola Luisa, bienvenida, se me ocurre que primero tendrías que usar un for para pedir los números y almacenarlos en un array (previamente creado con el tamaño indicado por el usuario), luego tendrías que instanciar una variable con el valor contenido en la primer posición del array, después con otro for, recorres el array desde la posición "1", y en cada iteración restas de la variable antes declarada, el valor de la actual posición.

Comment: Si laconsigna es usar solo una variable, y no arreglo, puedes pedir el primer número, he instanciar la variable con el, y luego con el for, pides los restantes que vas restando a la variable.

Answer (score 0):

Sería bueno que dejaras el código que has intentado para solucionar este ejercicio, para instruirte sobre tu desarrollo. Dado que no es así te muestro un ejemplo:

Suponiendo que ingresas los números 10,3,2,1,1 y el resultado de la resta tendría que ser 3 puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera

**Usando un arreglo**

En primera instancia tu variable "numero" tendría que ser un arreglo para almacenar los valores ingresados por consola y posteriormente usarlos para la resta, por ejemplo

```
int cantidad = 0;
        Console.WriteLine("Cuántos números quiere restar?");
        cantidad = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        int[] numero = new int[cantidad];

        for (int x = 0; x < cantidad; x++)
        {
            numero[x] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }
```

De esta manera tu arreglo "numero" se inicializa con un tamaño de indice al que ingresaste en "cantidad" y cada valor que ingrese por consola se almacenará en una posición del arreglo

Tomando los valores anteriores de ejemplo, tu arreglo quedaría así:

numero[0] = 10

numero[1] = 3

numero[2] = 2

numero[3] = 1

numero[4] = 1

**Con base a esto, podemos empezar a restar los valores de la misma variable, en este caso el arreglo numero**

```
    int resultado = numero[0];
    
            for (int i = 1; i < cantidad; i++)
            {
                resultado -= numero[i];
                Console.WriteLine(numero[i]);
            }

Console.WriteLine("La resta de los números es: " + resultado);
```

Primero se declara una variable para almacenar el resultado de la resta que va a ser igual al valor que contiene el arreglo en la posición 0 **(valor 10)**

Posteriormente se recorre el arreglo que contiene los valores que se van a restar desde la posición 1 del arreglo, debido a que el valor de la posición 0 del arreglo se tomo como base

Al final se imprime el resultado de la resta entre los numeros ingresados, en este caso da 3

**Usando una condición**

Sí no quieres usar un arreglo para restar los valores podrías hacerlo mediante una validación dentro del bucle, por ejemplo

```
        for (int i = 0; i < cantidad; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Digite un número");
            numero = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            if(i == 0)
            {
                resta = numero;
            }
            else
            {
                resta -= numero;
            }
        }
```

Así tomas siempre el primer valor como base y los demás los vas restando. **Son ejemplos con los que puedes guiarte y utilizarlos dependiendo de tus necesidades pero como siempre existen otras y mejores maneras de realizarlo**

Comment: Creo que la idea era hacerlo sin arreglo. Lo tienes fácil. Con un par de modificaciones quedará.